# IBM Watson Assistant integration with zendesk

Tags: integration, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, zendesk

I followed all steps listed here to integrate IBM Watson Assistant to Zendesk
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-zendesk#deploy-zendesk-routing

But I'm struggling to find exactly how am I suppose to pass values to Zendesk. The information provided is not clear enough, and if I request an agent, there's no information about the user, it shows in zendesk like this:
[image: Screen Shot 2021-04-12 at 11 08 10]

The documentation says:

> Specify the information by using the following syntax. Use the exact names (name and email) for the two name and value pairs.
>
> {
> user_payload : {
> name: '#{customerName}',
> email: '#{customerEmail}'
> }
> }

And after that:

> Decide whether to allow unidentified users to access Zendesk.
>
> The web chat integration allows anonymous users to initiate chats. However, as soon as you enable visitor authentication, Zendesk requires that the name and email of each user be provided. If you try to connect without passing the required information, the connection will be refused.
>
> If you want to allow anonymous users to connect to Zendesk, you can provide fictitious name and email data. Write a function to populate the two fields with fictitious name and email values.
>
> For example, your function must check whether you know the name and email of the current user, and if not, add canned values for them:
>
> const userPayload = {
> "name" : "Jane Doe1",
> "email" : "jdoe1@example.com",
> }

In my case, since users will access the assistant through a webview in an Android app, I have both name and email, and I don't need a whole authentication steps, all I want is to pass to zendesk those values, but can't exactly figure it out how. In the example, it just sets this constant but I don't know what to do with it, is there any code examples for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to pass the `email` and `username` to Zendesk so the agent will see them, those can be passed if you set the context of the conversation as follows

```
context.integrations.zendesk.pre_chat = { username: "John", email: "j@j.com"}
```

This should appear as tags in your agent's zendesk workspace.

If you want to use Zendesk security and have the chat authenticated, then you have to set security on for the web chat and embed a `user_payload` inside your JWT. (as described in the docs you have linked)